# How to link many TextViews with their resources

Tags: java, android, reference

I would like to connect many TextViews with resources, for example, I have got 21 TextViews in xml file which all create a table. I would like to simple attach them to my code, but I want to avoid 21 lines of code.. I thought about looping it, but I am probably wrong, because it doesn't work.

```
for (int id = 1; id < 21; id++)
    textView[id] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView+"id");
}
```

Comment: why not use a ListView or a RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

You can link ViewGroup which is your table here and iterate their childs.
Lets assume we have a linear layout named as mLinearLayout.

```
for(i=0; mLinearLayout.getChilds.size; i++){
    View child = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(child instanceof TextView)
       mList.add((TextView) child)
}
```

For more complex layouts you might need recursive functions to iterate child view groups.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `findViewById` you can try `findViewWithTag` because now you can use a string argument like what you want.

Of course, you'll probably have to adjust a few things to be able to use this.

Your `TextViews` will need to be a direct child of a parent layout in your xml and tag them: `android:tag="mytext1"`

Then in Java, for example:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
 ...
textview[i] = (TextView) parentLayout.findViewWithTag("mytext" + i);
```

And you can loop that `findViewWithTag`